# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'destoy

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, python-imaging-library

my project error showing exit button? what can i do...i checked more times

```
def iExit():
              iExit = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Customer Billing system","Confirm if you want to exit")
              if iExit > 0:
                   root.destoy()
                   return
```

Error....

```
t__.py", line 2095, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'destoy'
```

Comment: A typo,`destroy` not `destoy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is grammatical mistakes.check the spelling of destroy...

```
  After if `iExit > 0:` check this `root.destroy()`
```